# WSO2 API Manager Throws Exceptions for Paralle Requests

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 API Manger 1.8.0. I have enabled SAML2BearerAssertion Profile based OAuth Authorization Check for one of my REST APIs.

When I send parallel API requests from JMeter. I see these logs in the console.But response received correctly.

```
[2015-03-05 05:08:32,497]  WARN - APIKeyValidationServiceImpl Invalid session id for thrift authenticator.
[2015-03-05 05:08:32,495]  WARN - APIKeyValidationServiceImpl Invalid session id for thrift authenticator.
[2015-03-05 05:08:33,342]  WARN - ThriftKeyValidatorClientPool Login failed.. Authenticating again..
[2015-03-05 05:08:33,342]  WARN - ThriftKeyValidatorClientPool Login failed.. Authenticating again..
[2015-03-05 05:08:32,493]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2015-03-05 05:08:32,492+0000] from IP address
```

When I increase the parallel load further. In my case 125+ clients. It gives these exceptions. Also no response received.

```
2015-03-05 05:10:05,795]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-634
[2015-03-05 05:10:06,752]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-625
[2015-03-05 05:10:06,753]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-690
[2015-03-05 05:10:06,796]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-684
[2015-03-05 05:10:06,797]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-648
[2015-03-05 05:10:06,797]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-500
[2015-03-05 05:10:06,797]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-645
[2015-03-05 05:10:08,025] ERROR - ApiMgtDAO Error when executing the SQL 
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-41-thread-640] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:50; busy:50; idle:0; lastwait:60000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMgtDBUtil.getConnection(APIMgtDBUtil.java:138)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.validateKey(ApiMgtDAO.java:710)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService.validateKey(APIKeyValidationService.java:148)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.validateKey(APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.java:131)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:274)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:262)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-03-05 05:10:08,026] ERROR - ApiMgtDAO Error when executing the SQL 
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-41-thread-613] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:50; busy:50; idle:0; lastwait:60000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMgtDBUtil.getConnection(APIMgtDBUtil.java:138)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.validateKey(ApiMgtDAO.java:710)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService.validateKey(APIKeyValidationService.java:148)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.validateKey(APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.java:131)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:274)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:262)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-03-05 05:10:08,027] ERROR - APIKeyValidationServiceImpl Error in invoking validate key via thrift..
[2015-03-05 05:10:08,027] ERROR - APIKeyValidationServiceImpl Error in invoking validate key via thrift..
[2015-03-05 05:10:08,043] ERROR - ApiMgtDAO Error when executing the SQL 
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-41-thread-628] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:50; busy:50; idle:0; lastwait:60000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMgtDBUtil.getConnection(APIMgtDBUtil.java:138)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.validateKey(ApiMgtDAO.java:710)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService.validateKey(APIKeyValidationService.java:148)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.validateKey(APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.java:131)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:274)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:262)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-03-05 05:10:08,043] ERROR - JDBCPersistenceManager Error when getting a database connection object from the Identity data source.
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-41-thread-656] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:50; busy:50; idle:0; lastwait:60000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.persistence.JDBCPersistenceManager.getDBConnection(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:136)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.dao.ThriftSessionDAO.updateLastAccessTime(ThriftSessionDAO.java:188)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.ThriftAuthenticatorServiceImpl.isAuthenticated(ThriftAuthenticatorServiceImpl.java:186)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.validateKey(APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:274)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:262)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-03-05 05:10:08,043] ERROR - APIKeyValidationServiceImpl Error in invoking validate key via thrift..
[2015-03-05 05:10:08,044] ERROR - ThriftSessionDAO Error when getting an Identity Persistence Store instance.
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error when getting a database connection object from the Identity data source.
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.persistence.JDBCPersistenceManager.getDBConnection(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:143)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.dao.ThriftSessionDAO.updateLastAccessTime(ThriftSessionDAO.java:188)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.ThriftAuthenticatorServiceImpl.isAuthenticated(ThriftAuthenticatorServiceImpl.java:186)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.validateKey(APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:274)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:262)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-41-thread-656] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:50; busy:50; idle:0; lastwait:60000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.persistence.JDBCPersistenceManager.getDBConnection(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:136)
    ... 11 more
```

Is this the limit for a single APIM node? Or can I do some more tuning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see the message " Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds" this because thread wait for 60 second to get the database connection and fails to get the connection.

In master-datasource.xml file you can find following elements for each data source.

```
<maxActive>50</maxActive>
<maxWait>60000</maxWait>
```

where 
 MaxActive: The maximum number of database connections in use at one time.
If a connection is requested while MaxActive other connections are in use, APIM will wait for MaxWait milliseconds for a connection to be returned, and will then throw an exception if no connection was made available.

so you can increase the maxActive or maxWait . when running more in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

As of WSO2 APIM 3.0.0 This would required changes in your deployment.toml file as-

```
[database.apim_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2AM_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"
pool_options.maxActive=300
```

pool_options.maxActive has default value of 50 which can be overridden by this file. Similar changes could be done for shared_db etc.